# Creating a table in the database by activating the template

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have manually created a table in the database and it worked fine.

Now, whenever I activate my template, I want this table to be automatically created in the database, so I put the following code in the `functions.php` file:

```
register_activation_hook( get_template_directory()  . 'functions.php', 'Test_db_table' );
```

But no table was created after activating my template.

---

**Edit:**

By checking a plugin, I realized that it used this code as follows:

```
register_activation_hook( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'simple.php', 'create_db_table' );
```

Now I want to rewrite something like this for my template so that the desired table is created when my template is activated.

---

**Edit2:**

I also tried this way, but I still didn't get an answer:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'Test_db_table' );
```

---

**Edit3:**

I want to make sure that the problem is not with the table creation codes in the database; I created a plugin and put only the request to create a table in it.

After activating the plugin, a table was immediately created with the specifications I defined for it in the `functions.php` file.

**Plugin creation codes:**

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Creates the database table 
Description: Creates the database table.
Author: Author
Author URI: https://example.com/
Text Domain: Creates_the_database_table 
Version: 1.0.0
*/

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

// Creates the database table on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'test.php', 'Test_db_table' );
```

Now I'm looking for a way to do the same with my template.

**It means that the table will be created immediately after activating my template.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the last example you created in the question, you can provide a custom function to the activation hook for a plugin and after_switch_theme hook for a theme. Lets call the function 'create_custom_table'.

In our function we will need to include the WP admin file upgrade.php as it has the function required to execute the required SQL.

We can also use the $wpdb WordPress global to easily get the table prefix used so that the plugin can be more dynamic and the prefix is not hardcoded. You can also get the charset/collation info from $wpdb is you need to add that to the SQL.

I have added comments in the code so you can follow along. It is just an example so please change as you require.

When Used in a Plugin:

```php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_custom_table' );
```

When Used in a Theme:

```php
add_action("after_switch_theme", "create_custom_table");
```

The function to add in both cases will pretty much be the same, ie example function:

```php
function create_custom_table() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get the prefix of the WordPress database
    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    // Set the name of the table
    $table_name = $table_prefix . 'your_table_name';

    // Query for checking if table exists
    $table_exists = $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'");

    // If the table does not exist, create it
    if (!$table_exists) {

    // Set create SQL   
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$table_name}` (
     `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `field2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
     KEY `your_index` (`field1`,`field2`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

    // Include upgrade.php so we get access to dbDelta function
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    // Eecute the SQL
    dbDelta($sql);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. In order not to make my question long, I did not put the complete codes of my database table and I only want to implement how to create it automatically after activating my template. I put your code in the `functions.php`  file and after disabling and enabling the template, no table was created. Meanwhile, I tested this with the plugin and it worked easily. **Now I just want to implement this in my template**.

Comment: @Wp-PHP, thank you for the clarification, I have updated the answer, for the theme, you can use the after_switch_theme hook in functions.php

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved a big problem for me.